# to_xml method throwing (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)) exception in Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3.1, builder

This is really annoying `.to_xml` method in my rails app is throwing `(wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))` exception. Below is my code

```
string={:job_id=>'123'}
string.to_xml :skip_instruct => true, :root => 'line-item'
```

I digged into `ActiveRecord::Base` and found `to_xml` method

```
 def to_xml(options = {})
  require 'builder'
  options[:indent] ||= 2
  xml = options[:builder] ||= ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent])
  xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]
  xml.level_one do
   xml.tag!(:second_level, 'content')
  end
 end
```

What might be the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Search your code and libraries for someone who defines #to_xml with no arguments.

Comment: I tried to write `to_xml` method in a module I created, extended `string` from above to that module and called same method through module but same error.

Comment: That's the wrong `to_xml`, you want [`Hash#to_xml`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_xml). But that `to_xml` call is fine anyway. Are you saying that you've monkey patched your own `to_xml` in somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have monkey patched `to_xml` in module.

Comment: Okay, then what does your monkey patch look like?